# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors

I tried using a web app that would access h20 flow using REST API routes and when I tried to delete a frame (it would delete the frame after predicting), this happens:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://139.59.249.87:54321/3/Frames/1i3uso.
>   (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

I'm using ruby rails in order to build the web app. Any advice?
I used this route: `DELETE /3/Frames/{frame_id}`
and this coffee script is used:

```
deleteUploadFrame = (frame_id) ->
$.ajax
url: "http://139.59.249.87:54321/3/Frames/#{frame_id}"
method: 'DELETE'
```

This is the error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://139.59.249.87:54321/3/Frames/1i3uso.
>   (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

What should I do for this?

Answer (score -1):

Add these lines to application controller. This will fix your problem.

```
   after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

  def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  end
```

Comment: It still is producing the same error. My web app is running on a different domain to the H20 flow server